# Turbogears abort function automatically escapes HTML code

Tags: python, html, escaping, turbogears

I would like to use some HTML messages in the turbogears abort function.

Although the name does not match exactly  (I use the 'tg.abort' function), this is the abort definition I found : 
[abort](http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/classes.html#tg.controllers.util.abort)

The code used currently :

```
from tg import abort
message="The following {} occured, this is due to {}, please visit this url : {}".format(error, reason, url)
abort(status_code=502, detail=message)
```

I would like to have something like this :

```
from tg import abort
message="""The following error occured : {}</br>
           The most probable reason would be {} </br>
           <a href="{}">Your solution might be found here</a>
           """.format(error, reason, url)
abort(status_code=502, detail=message)
```

I think the content is automatically escaped.

The Html page generated from the abort function, endering something like this :

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
  Bad gateway.<br /><br />
The following error occured : hungry&lt;br/&gt;
The most probable reason would be : maybe you should eat &lt;/br&gt;
&lt;a href=&quot;http://dummyurl&quot;&gt;Your solution might be found here&lt;/a&gt;



 </body>
</html>
```

If you have any idea of how to insert html code without escaping, I would be very interested.
Also I really am focused on the abort method here, I am aware that I could use some dedicated page that would use a templating framework (like the rest of the website).

Thank you very much.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually exposed by the `controllers/error.py` code in your application. So if you want to expose the message from abort details you should fetch it and return it in the `ErrorController`.

This is now done by default on newly quickstarted projects ( see https://github.com/TurboGears/tg2devtools/blob/master/devtools/templates/turbogears/%2Bpackage%2B/controllers/error.py_tmpl#L27 ) but it was not done on old versions.